# Is it possible to update VSCode extension docs without bumping the version?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have published a VSCode extension in Marketplace under the version 0.1.0 (link to the extension [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mklein.cdk-snippets&ssr=false#overview))

I would like to do some adjustments and enhancements in the docs, specially the README file.

Is it possible to update the docs without bumping library version?

Since it doesn't has any impact in the library functionality, I would like to update the README and push the updates with `vsce publish`, but keeping the current version number.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: update the `patch` part of the version `0.1.1` and publish, otherwise the current users will never get the update

Comment: 1) Don't put moving things in README. I rather create a dedicate web site for my extension which I can update separately. 2) Since Marketplace only reads docs from your extension package, you have to submit a new version either 0.1.1 or 0.2.0.

Comment: Thanks for the comments 